# 〜てまいれ in Period Drama

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I'm watching Yae no Sakura and occasionally trying to understand grammar terms. I came upon this phrase:

> 殿様のため 会津のため しっかりと学んでまいれ｡

(for the sake of our Lord, for the Sake of Aizu. Study with all your efforts!) (my aided translation)

What role is 〜でまいれ playing here?
Is it the potential form of 参る (まいる)?

Jisho.org: to go; to come; to call. ​Humble (kenjougo), Usually written using kana alone.

So maybe: "You can go, and study with resolved effort!"?

It appears in a few other locations too:

> 即刻 戦を止めてまいれ｡
>
> 江戸に戻る｡ ついてまいれ｡
>
> 賊徒の首を取ってまいれ！
>
> ひるまずに 戦ってまいれ！

--

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「まい**れ**」 is the ***imperative*** form of 「まい**る**（参る）」.  It is not the potential form.

> 「Verb in Te-Form + まいる」

means:

> "to go and (verb)"

「参る」 is often used as a subsidiary verb like the above and when it is, it is written in all kana.  When used as a subsidiary verb in an imperative, it is for politeness.

> "Please go and study hard for our Lord and for the domain of Aizu!"